# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\subwo\package.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, cryptography, blockchain

I'm new to all this and I'm taking a Blockchain course to learn all I can from scratch. So the problem is that the guy from the course made me install the following:

```
Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/
Ganache: https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache
Truffle: https://www.trufflesuite.com/
Metamask
```

And also this resource:

```
Starter Kit: https://github.com/dappuniversity/starter_kit
```

So I installed all of that, including the starter kit to be able to follow along on the demo project. The thing is, the guy runs the starter kit app from the command prompt with the line "npm run start", so the app automatically opened in his browser. But when I do it, I get an ENOENT error which as I read, it indicates that a file is missing, I'll show a screenshot below:

[cmd error when trying to run app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ64W.png)

When I go to the folder in which I'm sure the "missing file" is located, I can see that it's there, in the folder where the whole app is installed:

[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Ktn.png)

I don't know if the cmd is searching in the right folder or what, and I honestly have no idea how to fix this. If anyone can help I'd deeply appreciate it, please let me know if you need to see the code of the app or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your package.json is in C:\Users\subwo\ethswap.

```
cd ethswap
npm run start
```

To eleborate. You're running npm run start from C:\Users\subwo, but your project directory is really in C:\Users\subwo\ethswap. So you need go one more directory down before running.

Comment: Wow that definitely changed everything but now I get a different error, here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/fEAEXyy

Comment: @Leon Did you install required packages with "npm install"

Comment: Sorry it's in spanish but the main error says that "React-scripts" is an unkown intern or extern command

Comment: Yes, I did. At least the ones the guy made me install, maybe I didn't install something that I need but I don't know what

Comment: Please follow this order : cd eth_swap > npm install > npm run start

Comment: if you just run npm install it should install everything identified by package.json

Comment: Thank you so much! that fixed the problem, cheers!!